# What's the difference in computation when I use final in Java compared to if I do not declare the variable to be final?

Tags: java

This is a question asked in one the written that I had given last week can anybody help me identify the difference

```
public class TestClass {
    static final  int a = 2;
    static final  int b = 3;

    static int c = 2;
    static int d = 3;

    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    int product1 = a * b;             //line A
    int product2 = c * d;             //line B
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `a` and `b` are declared `final`, there's the possibility that the compiler will in-line the calculation (the calculation being done at compile time). See the [Java Language Specification, section 15.28: Constant Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). That doesn't happen with `c` and `d`; the product will always be calculated at run time.

Answer (score 6):

Line A is candidate to be computed at compile-time because the fields are final. Line B is computed at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I believe   int product1 = a * b;    will be calculated during compilation itself, Since a and b was declared as final.

Answer (score 0):

variables `a` and `b` are final so the compiler will replace variables a and b with 2 and 3 in the line `product = a * b`

Comment: Not quite 'will'. The compiler can choose to inline.

Comment: @Bathsheba, isn't there  surety of it?

Comment: see JLS link in another answer.